# How to automate embeded Internet Explorer_Server on windows application

Tags: c#, automation

I'm trying to automate windows application that has Internet Explorer_Server element on it.
After I spend sometimes looking around the internet, I found most people get the HTML document from it.

The problem that I facing right now is I'm unable to extract the HTML document from it even after I'm able to get the HWnD.

Somebody can help me with this ?

Thank you